# Unable to get persistent socket connection with 3rd party daemon using Sails and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am a newbie to node.js and trying out Persistent Socket connection with a 3rd party daemon using ProtoBuf, sails and socket.io.

I've searched in Stack Overflow and other forums for the past 2 weeks and posting this question to get your valuable response.

Scenario:

There is a third party daemon (synchronous) running on port 5001 which should have persistent socket connection with the client. This daemon will wait for 30 seconds and close the socket, if no communication is happening.

Im unable to get Persistent Socket connection (using node's net API) between server.js and the 3rd party daemon with the below code sample. Every time a new socket id is created while sending EncryptRequest and UserRequest messages to the 3rd party daemon as server.js creates new socket and connects to 192.168.1.3:5001 every time.

So, I moved the socket initialization and connection above io.sockets.on('connection',...) line in server.js. In this case, I have only one socket connection established (Persistent), but its executing the callback on the controller to run multiple times.

### Steps I did:

a) I've created a sails app using the command "sails new webgui"

b) I've created a controller at webgui/api/controllers/SampleController.
And it has the method getAuth() which has a routing entry in webgui/config/routes.js

'/webgui/auth':'SampleController.getAuth'

Whenever I type http://mysamplehost.com:1337/webgui/auth it will talk to the 3rd party daemon and get the response.

c) The third party daemon connection logic is written in a new config file and stored at config/server.js.
I'm creating this prototype for a PoC using sails.

For now, SampleController.js is my client. And I'm not using any html at the moment.

The flow is:

```
         Sails Application

-----------------------------------------                     -------------------
|   mysamplehost on port 1337           |                     |                 |
|                                       |                     |                 |
|  -------------        ------------    |                     |                 |
|  |  Client   |        | HTTP     |    | Requires Persistent | 3rd Party       |
|  |           |        |Server    |    | Socket Connection   | daemon running  |
|  | SampleCon |  8081  |running on|    | on Port 5001        | on Port 5001    |
|  |troller.js |<------>|Port 8081 |<------------------------>|                 |
|  |           |        |          |    |                     |                 |
|  |           |        |          |    |                     |                 |
|  |           |        | server.js|    |                     |                 |
|  |           |        |          |    |                     |                 |
|  -------------        ------------    |                     |                 |
|                                       |                     |                 |
-----------------------------------------                     -------------------
```

### Question:

How to make the socket variable 'client' in config/server.js to connect with the 3rd party daemon persistently, without the response for the callback (in SampleController.js) executed many times?

Thanks,
Yogesh

### api/controllers/SampleController.js: (Client)

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://192.168.1.2:8081',{'force new connection': true});
module.exports = {
getAuth: function(req, res) {

    socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer"; // We are talking binary
    var ProtoBuf = require("protobufjs");
    var FPMessage = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("/webgui/api/protobuf/pb_common.proto").build("ProtoBuf.BaseMessage");

    var pb_login_builder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("/webgui/api/protobuf/pb_login.proto");

    var EncryptRequest = pb_login_builder.build("ProtoBuf.EncryptRequest");
    var EncryptResponse = pb_login_builder.build("ProtoBuf.EncryptResponse");
    var UserRequest = pb_login_builder.build("ProtoBuf.UserRequest");
    var UserResponse = pb_login_builder.build("ProtoBuf.UserResponse");

    socket.on('connect', function () {

        var msg = new EncryptRequest();
        msg.device_id = "";
        msg.msg_name = "EncryptRequest";
        msg.type = "none";
        socket.emit('message', msg.toArrayBuffer());

        socket.on('myMsg', function (evt) {
          try {
                var msgName = FPMessage.decode(evt);

                if(msgName.msg_name == 'EncryptResponse') {
                    var msg = EncryptResponse.decode(evt);
                    var hq_device_id = msg.device_id;
                    console.log("EncryptResponse - HQ Device ID : "+hq_device_id+"\n");

                    var msg2 = new UserRequest();
                    msg2.device_id = "";
                    msg2.msg_name = "UserRequest";
                    msg2.username = "Administrator";
                    socket.emit('message', msg2.toArrayBuffer());
                }
                else if(msgName.msg_name == 'UserResponse') {
                    var msg = UserResponse.decode(evt);
                    var hq_device_id2 = msg.device_id;
                    console.log("UserResponse - HQ Device ID : "+hq_device_id2);
                    socket.removeAllListeners();
                    return res.json(msg);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error: "+err+"\n");
            }
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log("disconnected.");
        });

    });
}
};
```

### config/server.js:

```
var sails = require('sails'),
path = require('path'),
ProtoBuf = require('protobufjs'),
net = require('net'),
server = require('http').createServer(function(request,response){}).listen(8081),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var HOST = "192.168.1.3";
var PORT = 5001;
var XD_HDR_LEN = 4; /* xtremed data header length (bytes) */

var client = new net.Socket();
var client_conn = client.connect(PORT, HOST);
client_conn.setTimeout(15000);

var builder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile(path.join(__dirname, "./../api/protobuf", "pb_common.proto")),
fpMessage = builder.build("ProtoBuf.BaseMessage");

server.on("listening", function(){
    sails.log.info('Server started');
});

server.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Failed to start server:", err);
    process.exit(1);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

   sails.log.info("New socket Connection - Socket id : "+socket.id);  

   socket.on("message", function(message) {
        try {
            var buf = addMessageHeader(message);
            sails.log.info("Connected to: " + HOST + ":" + PORT);
            client.write(buf);
        } catch(err) {
            sails.log.error("websocket message failed! ", err);
        }           
   });
  client_conn.on("data", function(data2) {
     var data3 = stripMessageHeader(data2);
     io.emit('myMsg',data3);
  });

  client_conn.on('close', function() {
    sails.log.info('Connection closed');
   });

  socket.on("close", function() {
      socket.disconnect();
      //socket.removeAllListeners();
      sails.log.info("Client socket closed." );
   });
 });

/*  In: Buffer object
 * Out: Buffer object
*/
function addMessageHeader(message)
{
var version = 1;
var options = 0;

var buf = new Buffer(message.length + XD_HDR_LEN);

//Message header: { u32 version:4, options:4, length:24; }
buf[0]  = version; /* TODO: support options */
buf[1]  = (message.length & 0xFF);
buf[2]  = ((message.length & 0xFF00) >> 8);
buf[3]  = ((message.length & 0xFF000) >> 16);
message.copy(buf, XD_HDR_LEN);
return buf;
}

/*
 *  In: Buffer object
 * Out: Buffer object
*/
function stripMessageHeader(buffer)
{
/* note: slice uses existing buffer */
return buffer.slice(XD_HDR_LEN);
}
```

Comment: The first thing I would say is that if you're really a newbie to Node you're trying to do way too much too fast.  This doesn't even look like a Sails app.  You shouldn't have to do most of those requires if you're within the Sails framework.  Also, Sails has socket.io functionality already included that you should learn about, and without the client side code it's hard to tell what might be going on here.

Comment: @HeadCode I've removed the unwanted requires from the above config/server.js and added the steps that I did to create the sails app and the application's flow. Please refer to my updated post again.

Comment: The diagram really helps!  I'm too busy to look at this now, but I will check back in this weekend if you haven't already solved it.  I do have one question: Are you running two separate node apps?  One on port 1337 and one on port 8081?

Comment: @HeadCode Thanks for your help. I will try to fix. I'm not running two node apps. The node application uses sails which runs on port 1337 and the Http Server is running on port 8081 which is used to communicate between the sails controller and the config file (server.js). The config file has a client side TCP socket opened (using node's net API) on port 5001 which talks to the 3rd party daemon.

Comment: ANSWER: I've moved the TCP Socket connection(client_conn) outside the 'message' event handler in server.js to prevent multiple connections being created, whenever a new ProtoBuf message is processed. This results in only single socket connection created.